# operator<< overloading ostream

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, ostream

In order to use cout as such : std::cout << myObject, why do I have to pass an ostream object? I thought that was an implicit parameter.

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const myClass &o) {

    out << o.fname << " " << o.lname;
    return out;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't adding another member function to `ostream`, since that would require redefining the class.  You can't add it to `myClass`, since the `ostream` goes first.  The only thing you can do is add an overload to an independent function, which is what you're doing in the example.

Answer (score 2):

Only if it is a member function of the class that would otherwise be the first argument. Thus, it would be:

```
class ostream {
    ...
    ostream &operator << (const myClass &o);
    ...
};
```

Since `ostream` was written long before your class, you see the problem of getting your class in there. Thus, we must implement the operator as a freestanding function:

```
(return type) operator << ( (left hand side), (right hand side) );
```

When operators are implemented as member-functions of classes, the left hand side is `this`, and the argument becomes the right hand side. (For binary operators - unary operators work similarly.)

Answer (score -1):

Because you are overloading a free function, not a member function.